# Display comment without refreshing the view Asp.Net Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, controller

Is This Possible Without Ajax ?

I Have a form for comments:

```
  <form asp-action="CommentUser">
<input type="hidden" name="videoid" value="@Model.Id" />    
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Your Comment :</label>
    <textarea name="comentuser" class="form-control">       
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Controller :

```
 [HttpPost]
   public IActionResult CommentUser(string comentuser,int videoid)
    {
        int iduser = _database.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == User.Identity.Name).Id;
        Comment comment = new Comment();
        comment.TextComment = comentuser;
        comment.VideoId = videoid;
        comment.UserId = iduser;
        _database.Comments.Add(comment);
        _database.SaveChanges();
        return Ok();
    }
```

thanks

Comment: Please note that you need to make HTTP request(s) to your action method from browser client, without do form submit and refresh the page, Ajax or fetch etc would be used. Besides, your action method `CommentUser` just help save new created comment and return okresult,  this action method seems not help display comment.

Comment: What do you suggest for this?

Comment: `What do you suggest for this?` Using Ajax or fetch api etc to make HTTP request, and make action method return partial view or comment data, then update view content based on returned data on js client side.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use ajax and partial views for the same. Display the comment blocks as a partial view. Use Ajax to send the backend request and update the partial view.